# How to compare two strings that are ordered differently in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, comparison, compare

I have the following two strings:

```
[DATEREMIND] = {'20/10/2013' -> ^/} [EVENTDATE] = {^ -> '20/10/2013'/} [OCCURREDFLAG] = {0 -> 1/}    
[EVENTDATE] = {^ -> '20/10/2013'/} [DATEREMIND] = {'20/10/2013' -> ^/} [OCCURREDFLAG] = {0 -> 1/}
```

They are exactly the same content, but ordered differently.

Is there a simple way to compare the these two strings that will result in them being deemed equal? It can't be done by comparing the length as the dates may change but the length then would not.

Comment: What is your problem ? did you get any errors ?

Comment: Using = the two string evaluate as not being equal. I want them to evaluate as being equal as the content is the same, just ordered differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a function that first converts each character to its ASCII value and subsequently totals up the values of all the digits in the ASCII representation.

Function as follows:

```
create function dbo.getAsciiRepresentation
(
    @string varchar (max)
)
returns int
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @position int, @aux char(3), @myvalFirst varchar(2000)='1' 
DECLARE @intOfVal bigint
declare @total int, @myval varchar(2000)='1'
SET @position = 1            
WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@string)
BEGIN
SET @aux = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)) 
SET @myvalFirst = @myvalFirst+ replace(@aux,' ','0')
SET @position = @position + 1
END

set @myval = @myvalFirst
set @position = 1    
set @total = 0
WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@myval)
BEGIN
set @aux = SUBSTRING(@myval, @position, 1)
set @total = @total + cast(@aux as int)
SET @position = @position + 1
END
return @total
END
```

This will then return the same value as long as the same characters are present, regardless of the order.